# count all subsets of integers (including negative) that sum to x

Tags: c++, algorithm, subset-sum

I am given an array of max length 40 containing integers in [-10^9;10^9]. I am also given the expected sum X which lies in [0;10^9]. Now I am supposed to give the total amount of subsets that sum to X. I can't figure out a way to deal with the negative numbers. I first tried the brute-force approach which works fine for small input arrays but is unusable for large ones:

```
auto r = 0ULL;
for(auto i = 0ULL; i < (1ULL << n) - 1ULL; ++i) {
    auto x = 0ULL;
    for(auto j = 0ULL; j < n; ++j) {
        if(i & (1ULL << j)) {
            x += values[j];
        }
    }
    r += x == sum;
}
cout << r << '\n';
```

Then I tried memorizing the intermediate results of the additions so I don't have to calculate them more then once for the same elements. But that consumes ALOT of space ( should be around 9 TB for inputs of length 40 x) ). Can someone give me a hint on a better approach?

Comment: This reads like it's from some contest/challenge/competitive coding/hacking site. Is it? If your goal is to learn C++, you won't learn anything there. In nearly all cases, like this one, the correct solution is based on a mathematical or a programming trick. If you don't know what the trick is and attempt to code a brute-force approach, the program runs slow and fails for that reason. If you're trying to learn C++, you won't learn anything from meaningless online contest sites [but only from a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: What techniques were taught in class before this homework assignment was given? Recursion? Loops? Linked lists? Arrays? Something else? If this is a homework assignment it means that you are obviously expected to use a specific technique for solving it. So, can you explain what techniques were presented in class, that this homework assignment is expected to demonstrate?

Comment: http://panzi.github.io/numbers-js/ Someone has done this for +-*/ so just cut down their solution.

Comment: this is an advanced lecture that's supposed to give you an introduction to coding competitions, knowing basic programming concepts like you mentioned is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum range and item count looks too large for dynamic programming due to memory reason.

But limit of 40 items allows to apply something like **"meet-in-the-middle"** principle.

Separate the first 20 items and count sums for all possible subsets - just walk through 2^20 subsets *(including empty one!)*  (using recursion or binary representation of subset number or some other way) and write sums in the map containing pairs `(sum, count)`.

Do the same for the second half. Note that size of maps is quite reliable.

Walk though the first map keys and look for corresponding keys from the second map. Pseudocode:

```
for sum in map1:
    if map2.contains(X - sum):
        result += map1[sum] * map2[X - sum]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: there is a recurrence you can use. Let `num_subsets[i][k]` be the number of subsets of `values[0], values[1], ..., values[i]` that can sum to `k`. Then

```
num_subsets[i][k] = num_subsets[i - 1][k – values[i]] + num_subsets[i - 1][k]
```

Then `num_subsets[n-1][x]` is your answer.

Comment: Hm, doesnt this assume strictly positive inputs? If values[i] is negative the sum increases

Comment: @Yamahari No that's perfectly fine.

Comment: @orlp the data range is big, the 2d array can lead to huge space cost.

Comment: @KunHu I never mentioned a 2D array? You can implement `num_subsets[i][k]` in many ways, a recursive function, hash maps, etc.

Comment: @orlp the number of different subset sums is still huge. For example, when i is 30, and  subset size is 15, there can be 155,117,520 different subsets (sums), don't we need to store all these results?

Comment: @KunHu If `k` is greater than all of them, potentially, yes. That's why this dynamic programming solution is pseudo-polynomial time. If `k` grows too large to store this problem is NP-hard. But 10^9 isn't at that point yet, that's around 8 gigabytes.